# Create belongs_to association to another model from a concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a polymorphic model and one of several normal models.

```rb
class Task
  belongs_to :taskable, polymorphic: true
end

class Building
  include Taskable
end
```

And I have the following concern/mixin.

```rb
module Taskable
  extends ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :tasks, as: :taskable
  end

  class_methods do
    def tasks
      Task.where(taskable: all)
    end
  end
end
```

In our app we need to be able to join Task on specific models, such as building. We were able to achieve this by adding the following belongs_to to the Task model.

```rb
belongs_to :building, -> { where(tasks: { taskable_type: Building.name }) }, foreign_key: taskable_id, foreign_type: Building.name
```

However, we need to add this belongs_to manually each time we want to make another model Taskable. We want the concern to create a belongs_to association on Task automatically. We used metaprogramming to create the association for the extending class but the association was only created when we loaded the class. I want the belongs_to to be created when the console is started, same with the server.

```rb
# In Taskable concern.
# Is only called when we load a performable in the console.
Task.belongs_to class.name.to_sym, -> { where(tasks: { taskable_type: class.name }) }, foreign_key: taskable_id, foreign_type: class.name
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: The default for the development environment is to lazy load, you can change it eager load by setting `config.eager_load = true` in development.rb.  The classes will then be eager loaded as they are in production and qa.

Comment: The con being that it will slow startup.

Comment: Oh right, so that's what did it. Thanks!